# How do I build the YAML PECL extension for Windows when there isn't already a DLL available?

Tags: php, c++, windows, yaml, pecl

I have PHP 8.2.4 installed on my Windows machine and I would like to enable the YAML extension.  The instructions that I have followed in the past are to download the the Windows DLL from the PECL YAML site: https://pecl.php.net/package/yaml

However, the site (at this point in time) doesn't have a built DLL for PHP 8.2.

I tried following the steps provided in the following document but it wasn't generating the correct DLL:
https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild

When I tried copying the DLL into the php extensions folder and enabling it in the php.ini, it gives an error for that extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I did to compile a compatible version using the following site as a guide:
https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild_sdk_2#building_pecl_extensions_with_phpize

1. Install Virtual Studio Build Tools 2019
   Components

   - Windows Universal C Runtime
   - C++ Build Tools core features
   - MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools (Latest)
   - C++ CMake tools for Windows
   - Testing tools core features - Build Tools
   - C++ v14.29 (16.10) MFC for v142 build tools (x86 & x64)
   - Windows 10 SDK (10.0.20348.0)
2. Download Windows PHP and Windows PHP Development Package (on download page) https://windows.php.net/download/
3. Download libyaml from PHP pecl deps https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/deps/
4. Create a build folder for libraries (D:\build)
5. Extract the Windows PHP Development Package into that folder
6. Extract the libyaml into that folder as "libyaml"
7. Clone the yaml repo https://github.com/php/pecl-file_formats-yaml.git into that folder
8. Clone the Microsoft PHP binary tools https://github.com/Microsoft/php-sdk-binary-tools.git into that folder and checkout the latest tag (php-sdk-2.2.0)
9. Open the visual studio app, *x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019* (you can find it in the start menu; search for *native*)
10. Change directory to the php-sdk-binary-tools folder and run `phpsdk-vs16-x64.bat`
11. Set the path to include the PHP that you download and the development package folders on the path: `set PATH=D:\php-8.2.4;D:\build\php-8.2.4-devel-vs16-x64;%PATH%`
12. Change directory to the pecl folder "pecl-file_formats-yaml"
13. Run `phpize`
14. Then run `configure --with-yaml --with-php-build=..\libyaml`
15. Run `nmake`

The yaml dll file will be located in the subdirectory, *x64\Release* as *php_yaml.dll*

Comment: I tried it on Windows 11 / VS 2022 / PHP 8.2.8. Sadly it fails on "nmake".
https://github.com/Microsoft/php-sdk-binary-tools/tree/php-sdk-2.2.0 seems to be a dead project by 2023.